# Data on refugee migration

Tags: data-request, migration

Are there any current data sets on the migration of refugees in Europe available? As information seems to be sparse, I don't really care what kind of data. For example, data on migration routes or registration data would be interesting, preferably from the governments or the EU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [global-refugees.info](http://www.global-refugees.info/)'s [data](https://github.com/NikolaSander/refugees/raw/gh-pages/refugees-interactiv-data.xlsx). It's available as a excel spreadsheet (.xlsx). And they also have some code explaining the process they used for making the visualizations on their website and on github
https://github.com/NikolaSander/refugees/

**UNHCR database**

The main source of all the articles and visualizations is this http://popstats.unhcr.org/en/persons_of_concern

**UNDATA**

Some journalists also use this as their source http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNHCR&f=indID%3AType-Ref, although many argue that it's basically UNHCR's data afterreported.

Comment: The UNHCR database seems to be fairly up to date.

Comment: Yes, I think the UNHCR database is the best source, sometimes it requires a little bit more or pre-processing but it's always well curated and up-to-date.

Answer (score 6):

One possible source would be [The Migrant Files](http://www.themigrantsfiles.com/). It's a cross-border journalism project. If you scroll down on the main page, you'll find links to data, such as:

- [All data on deporations](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rDThuJ1HVTsWWPEvauOIGuY0kd7h8fGkrxebmlMt7h4/edit#gid=0)
- [All data on migrant and refugee deaths](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YNqIzyQfEn4i_be2GGWESnG2Q80E_fLASffsXdCOftI/edit?usp=sharing)

etc

There are links and references in each of the data sources.